# Modifying 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, 2d

I have to write a simple cinema booking program using a 2d array. all i can do 100% is printing the array here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Cinema seat outlet :\n\n");

    int i, j, a[10][10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            printf("%d", a[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\nMake a booking for what seat U desire :\n\n");
}
```

Now I just want to book the seat in a specific location and change it to a 1. To indicate that seat is booked. 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How are you accepting the location from the user?

Comment: Example: `a[3][4] = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

The basic program you've asked , you can modify further for your use

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()

{
  printf("Cinema seat outlet :\n\n");
  int i, j, a[10][10],row,column;
  memset(a,0x00,sizeof(a));   /* all the array is initialized to zero*/
  printf("below shows the seating arrangement \n\n");

  printf(" \t");              /* compensate offset of row number*/

  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)    /* Prints the column number (+1 since i starts from 0)*/
  printf(" %d ",i);

  printf("\n");
  for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\t",(i+1));        /* Prints the row number (+1 since i starts from 0)*/   
        for(j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
              printf(" %d ",  a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n\nEnter the row number of the set you desire:\n\n");
  scanf("%d",&row);
  printf("\n\nEnter the column number of the set you desire:\n\n");
  scanf("%d",&column);
  a[row-1][column-1] = 1;       /* set the seat booked (-1 cz; user express data in +1     format)*/
  printf("The seats of the theatre\n\n");

  printf(" \t");              /* compensate offset of row number*/     
  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)    /* Prints the column number (+1 since i starts from 0)*/
  printf(" %d ",i);

  printf("\n");
  for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\t",(i+1));        /* Prints the row number (+1 since i starts from 0)*/   
        for(j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
              printf(" %d ",  a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: If that satisfies your requirement please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can always start with array index as row and column like `a[row][column]`.
Now you can set this specific seat designated by `row` and `column` as being taken, or check whether this specific seat is taken or not.

Comment: hehe I`m new to c so dont know exacly how to do it :0